If the user is logged in, it cannot find the element and gives an error
When you find the login button on the relevant page, there is no problem and it works fine. However, if the user is logged in to the page, normally the Login button cannot be found and the program gives an error.
What I want is to check when the page loads and if the login button appears, the user login code should run. If the home page that you have logged in directly appears, you can continue other operations, such as clicking on another area.
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");

var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service,chromeOptions);
var Url = "https://www.sampleeeeeee.com";
driver.Url = Url;

WaitForPageLoad(driver);
 var loginBtn = FindElementWithJs(driver, "button.btn-standard.call-to-action") as IWebElement;
 loginBtn.Click();

The login button here appears if there is no login. If the user is logged in, the system does not work because he cannot find the login button here.
What path should I follow?
I queried the login button with bool. If it comes back true, run different codes. But when it cannot find the login button, bool also gives an error.
static object FindElementWithJs(IWebDriver driver,string command, object[] options=null,bool costumJs=false,int recheck = 4, int timeout=5,string message = "CANNOT_FOUND_ELEMENT")
{
    int elementReCheck = 1;
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if(elementReCheck > recheck)
            {
                throw new Exception(message);
            }
            string queryObject = costumJs == false ? $"return document.querySelector('{command}')" : command;
            var element = RunJsCommand(driver, queryObject,options);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
            if(element != null)
            {
                return element;
            }
            else
            {
                elementReCheck++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}


Please [edit] your question to include a [repro], which should also contain all relevant HTML.
